# Adding dynamic new columns

Tags: r, dplyr

The problem that I am trying to solve is as follows:
I have a dataframe, say c and it has a column name called "WasteType". Now, "WasteType" contains several factor values (T, U, V etc) and this list may vary with different dataset.
I would want to create new columns T, U etc based on the different factor values and it is going to be dynamic. Here is the function that I have created. Would be helpful if I get some direction and guidance on this.

To start with and see if my function is working. I took first four lines from the dataframe and the WasteType contains "T" and "U" only. So, I want to add a column T which will show 1 if WastType column has 1 and 0 otherwise. Similarly for column U.

```
d<-function(c,x=c$WasteType){
  x1<-unique(x)
  print (x1)
  s<-length(x1)
  n<-ncol(c)
  print(s)
    for(i in 1:s){
      print(x1[i])
      mutate(c,ifelse(x==c(x1[i]),1,0))  ##adding a new column
      colnames(c)[n+1]<-x1[i]            ##renaming the column
      return(c)
  }
}
d(c,x=c$WasteType)
```

I cannot figure out that why the above function is not able to read the mutate() function.

I am still at a very nascent stage when it comes to programming in R. Though, I looked through several questions before posting it here. The problem may look silly but I am not able to solve it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution without writing a function using `sapply`:

```
    c <- data.frame(WasteType = c('T', 'U', 'T', 'U'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    d <- t(sapply(c$WasteType,function(x) as.numeric(unique(c$WasteType) %in% x)))
    colnames(d) <- unique(c$WasteType)
> cbind(c,d)
  WasteType T U
1         T 1 0
2         U 0 1
3         T 1 0
4         U 0 1
```

(you will get a warning that for object `d` row.names will not be used as there are duplicates, which is ok and can be ignored)

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your function a little:

```
c <- data.frame(WasteType = c('T', 'U', 'T', 'U'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d <-function(c, x = c$WasteType) {
    x <- c$WasteType
    x1 <- unique(x)
    s <-length(x1)
    n <- ncol(c)

    for(i in seq_len(s)) {
        c <- mutate(c, ifelse(x == x1[i], 1, 0))  
        colnames(c)[n + i] <- x1[i]
    }

    return(c)
}

d(c, x = c$WasteType)

  WasteType T U
1         T 1 0
2         U 0 1
3         T 1 0
4         U 0 1
```